# How can I represent a polkadotjs type for a custom generic Enum?

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm uncertain how I can structure the generic variant of a polkadotjs type for an on-chain Enum that looks sort of like this:

```
#[derive(TypeInfo, Debug, Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyEnum<T: Codec> {
    OptionA,
    OptionB(T),
}
```

I get down to my polkadotjs types and:

```
...
  MyEnum: {
    _enum: {
      OptionA: null,
      OptionB: '...???',
    },
  },
```

What should go in OptionB to represent the generic portion?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, there shouldn't be any generic. (I didn't use this anymore since metadata 14)

It must be an exact type.

```
"Balance": "u128"
```

You can't write `"Balance": "T"`. Unless you tell it `"T": "u128"`.

So, you need to check what is your `T` on the runtime level.

e.g. https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/85bfeda3161bafb6a42f63b57b169265820972a1/runtime/crab/types.json#L9-L14